Old iMac, 1.7ghz 8gb any ubuntu system I can use?
I have a late 2015 iMac with, I think, a 1.7ghz processor, 8gb ram, 1tb memory. It is running very slow, appears to be hard-drive. Going to purchase an external ssd to use as new hard-drive. Ubuntu says system requirements 2ghz. Is there an ubuntu system I can use on this old mac? Main programs used are Libre Office, Reaper, and viva designer. Considering a mini-mac, but that would be expensive just to convert to linux. Also, not very computer knowledgeable.

I would try it (22.04LTS or 24.0TS) - run a usb session and see how it performs (it’ll always be slower running from usb than ssd, but it’ll at least show you if it’ll work). If not, Lubuntu is lighter weight.

FYI:  The oldest device I use in Quality Assurance testing of Ubuntu Desktop systems, is a 2005 HP Compaq, that I suspect is much less powerful in all regards to your device (Core2Duo, less RAM, 80GB spinning rust HDD etc)... but specifications aren't the whole picture anyway.. ie. I consider the GPU (graphics hardware) as well...  If you're wondering about speed of my ancient intel Core2Duo CPU, I have no idea, as that is not something I consider is actually important...  I'd look at CPU spec & not worry about FSB/speed

The 1.7GHz frequency is probably the base frequency before turbo boost. It should not be a problem

I use Ubuntu regularly on a 2014 iMac and it works very well.

If there is any issue after installing Ubuntu, feel free to ask a question.

I'm looking to purchase an external hard drive/ssd and run from that. Any opinion on which brand? What am I looking for in the graphics hardware on the computer?

The GPU is a intel 6000.

I am running ubuntu-latest version- from a Seagate bootable drive, using the late-2015 mac desktop. The computer is hardwired to internet. None of the wireless devices are registering. In the setting panel: needs plug in for blue tooth. Do I need to buy a different mouse and keyboard? Do I need to download something else? My other question is: Is there anyway around the "new system" set-up that initiates when I use the bootable?

I use Kubuntu 24.04 regularly on a 2014 iMac and it works very well. Ubuntu 24.04 or any flavor of that should work in your computer.
In my 2014 iMac, the WiFi driver is not supported out of the box, but once I connect to internet using Ethernet/USB tethering, Ubuntu provides a WiFi driver in the "Additional Drivers" tab in the Software & Updates program. You may face the same issue in your iMac.
